# onScreenCall() method in CallScreeningService is not getting called, I want this function to fetch call details

Tags: android, android-studio, service

I am using following code to register the service in Manifest.

```
 <service android:name=".CallScreenService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_SCREENING_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.telecom.CallScreeningService"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

This is my service class that is extending the CallScreeningService.

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public class CallScreenService extends CallScreeningService {

    @Override
    public void onScreenCall(Call.Details callDetails) {
        CallResponse.Builder response = new CallResponse.Builder();
        Toast.makeText(this, callDetails.getHandle().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure your app is the selected phone app in the device

Comment: As for me It works in android 12 emulator but not on physical device I am using Poco X3.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register you app for call screening role first:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/CallScreeningService#onScreenCall(android.telecom.Call.Details)

```
 private static final int REQUEST_ID = 1;

 public void requestRole() {
     RoleManager roleManager = (RoleManager) getSystemService(ROLE_SERVICE);
     Intent intent = roleManager.createRequestRoleIntent(RoleManager.ROLE_CALL_SCREENING);
     startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ID);
 }

 @Override
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     if (requestCode == REQUEST_ID) {
         if (resultCode == android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK) {
             // Your app is now the call screening app
         } else {
             // Your app is not the call screening app
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: I implemented the role request code and got RESULT_OK in onactivityResult , but still CallScreeningService doesn`t get invoked when an incoming call comes , testing on android 11 device.

Comment: @RavikantTiwari did you found any solution for android 11?

Comment: Probably this is too late to reply, but just to help someone else who stumble across this page: 

The service is only called when a new incoming or outgoing call is added which is not in the user's contact list. and "Further, only calls which are not in the user's contacts are passed for screening."

Comment: Only calls where the handle scheme is PhoneAccount.SCHEME_TEL are passed for call screening. Further, only calls which are not in the user's contacts are passed for screening, unless the CallScreeningService has been granted Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS permission by the user. For outgoing calls, no post-dial digits are passed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have implemented `onStartCommand` remove it. Remove `onBind` and `onUnbind` as well.

Answer (score 0):

need permissions

```
permission.READ_CALL_LOG,permission.READ_CONTACTS
```

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77711455/i-want-to-get-hold-of-phone-number-programmatically-as-the-phone-is-ringing-in-a/77762680#77762680) contains the full code about how to use `CallScreeningService` and `onScreenCall` to get the incoming call details.