# How to fetch incoming call number using CallScreeningService api

Tags: java, android, android-broadcast, callscreeningservice

I want to fetch the incoming call number in my Android app using Callscreeningservice api but I don't know how to implement it and how to use that service in activity

I created a class extending Callscreeningservice but how to register this service in my activity?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77711455/i-want-to-get-hold-of-phone-number-programmatically-as-the-phone-is-ringing-in-a/77762680#77762680) about how to use `CallScreeningService` to get incoming phone number.

Just note that the `CallScreeningService` only works on Android >= 29. So if you want to get incoming number from older devices you need to add extra methods.